# How do i create a table in .jsp file

Tags: java

Im having trouble creating a table in the .jsp file
Also i am working with a database so i have a controller and service files

My table:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>x</th>
        <th>y</th>
        <th>z</th>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td>this is where i need to put the value in</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    
</table>
```

I am using maven if that is important.
How would i write the controller and service classes for this to work.

I am using getMapping and postMapping in my controller
I also have the c taglib for the if, foreach, etc

It says its a duplicate, so ill go in detail
This is my controller:

```
    @Controller
    public class Cont {
    @Autowired
    Serv service;
    
    @GetMapping("getX")
    public String getX(HttpServletRequest req) {
        req.getSession().removeAttribute("p");
        req.getSession().removeAttribute("o");
        req.getSession().setAttribute("z", service.getX());
        return "nameOfJSPfileP";
    }

    @GetMapping("getY")
    public String getY(@RequestParam("idX")Integer id, HttpServletRequest req) {
        req.getSession().setAttribute("p", service.getY(id));
        req.getSession().setAttribute("o", service.getX(id));
        return "nameOfJSPFileG";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("getZ")
    public String getZ(@RequestParam("idP")Integer idY, Model m) {
        m.addAttribute("name", service.getG(idY));
        m.addAttribute("numb", service.getNumb(idY));
        return "nameOfJSPfileG";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("goBack")
    public String back() {
        return "nameOfJSPFileP";
    }
}
```

This is my service:

```
    public List<X> getX(){
        return Xrepo.findAll();
    }
    
    public List<Y> getY(Integer idX){
        return Yrepo.findByX(idX);
    }
    
    public X getX(Integer idX) {
        return Xrepo.findById(idX).get();
    }
    
    public List<G> getG(Integer idY){
        return Grepo.getForY(idY);
    }
    
    public Integer getNumb(Integer idY) {
        return ur.getNumb(idY);
    }
```

I need to populate the table with values from x y z, but i dont know how to put lets say if table x has names, that needs to be in a table, how do i put the exact values, how are the values written in .jsp file

**answer**
I wasnt using ${} which is a must

This is for a dropdown table, you always have to use form

```
<form action="/getY" method="get">
        X:<select name="idX">
            <c:forEach items="${x's}" var="x">
                <option value="${x.idX}">${x.name}</option>
            </c:forEach>
            </select> <input type="submit" value="Show" />
</form>
```

Also, make sure you are using the same names here that you use in the controller

```
    <c:if test="${!empty o}">
        Text: ${o.name}
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Surname</th>
                <th>Date</th>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach items="${p}" var="p">
                <tr>
                    <td>${p.name}</td>
                    <td>${p.surname}</td>
                    <td><a href="/getZ?idY=${p.idY}">Date</a></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </c:if>
```

Comment: Wow , way too broad.  I suggest that you read a tutorial, but basically you need to read the data in a servlet, store in a List variable, call the jsp and then the jsp can loop through the list creating the HTML